# Error al usar OpenFileDialog en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

estaba intentando usar OpenFileDialog en mi boton para que cuando lo presione me salga el dialogo, lo hago del siguiente modo:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim OpenFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .FileName = ""
            .Filter = ""
            .Title = ""
            .ShowDialog()
            TextBox1.Text = .FileName
            infectedfile = TextBox1.Text
        End With
    End Sub
```

Pero me devuelve el error:

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. (BC30506) - C:\Users\Androide\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Form1\Form1\MainForm.vb:19,99
```

Como puedo evitar este error?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que creas el openfiledialog de manera dinámica, para esto debes indicar que es un nuevo objeto, de igual manera recomiendo que empieces a utilizar el archivo solo cuando es seleccionado, para esto podrías utilizar el dialogresult de tu openfiledialog.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    With OpenFileDialog1
        .Title = ""
        .Filter = ""
    End With
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        infectedfile = TextBox1.Text
    End If

End Sub
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El error parece indicar que el botón `Button1` no está creado correctamente.

Si no has creado el botón puedes crearlo desde el diseñador de formularios seleccionando el botón en la barra de herramientas y dibujándolo con el ratón en el formulario.

Si lo has creado en el archivo MainForm.designer.vb, que es el fichero en el que se encuentra el código creado por el diseñador de formularios, debería aparecer una declaración similar a:

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(62, 45)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
```